# How to add custom Namespace to Telemetry events

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-application-insights

According to [this post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/essentials/metrics-custom-overview?toc=%2Fazure%2Fazure-monitor%2Ftoc.json#namespace), I should be able to attach a custom *namespace* property to the *baseData* object. But the [`TelemetryClient.TrackEvent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.applicationinsights.telemetryclient.trackevent?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_ApplicationInsights_TelemetryClient_TrackEvent_System_String_System_Collections_Generic_IDictionary_System_String_System_String__System_Collections_Generic_IDictionary_System_String_System_Double__) method and its overloads do not seem to provide a way to specify the *namespace* property. Now, all my custom events are categorized under the **azure.applicationinsights** namespace.

Comment: TrackEvent method is used for custom events, not for custom metrics, is this a mistake in your question?

Comment: Thanks. I just noticed you cannot even filter events by *namespace* on the portal.

Comment: How to do it in .net 8?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For metrics, you should use `GetMetric` and `TrackValue` methods to send the `custom metrics`. The `TrackEvent` method is actually for `custom events`.

To specify the `custom namespace property`, you should use the code below:

```
// Note, add "using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Metrics;" to use MetricIdentifier

MetricIdentifier id = new MetricIdentifier("Custom Metric Namespace","ComputerSold", "FormFactor", "GraphicsCard", "MemorySpeed", "BatteryCapacity", "StorageCapacity");
Metric computersSold  = _telemetryClient.GetMetric(id);
computersSold.TrackValue(110,"Laptop", "Nvidia", "DDR4", "39Wh", "1TB");
```

The related doc is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/get-metric#how-to-use-metricidentifier-when-there-are-more-than-three-dimensions).

Another way is to use the `TrackMetric` method, but it is not recommended now(see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-custom-events-metrics#trackmetric) for the reason). Anyway, if using `TrackMetric` method, the code looks like below:

```
        MetricTelemetry metric = new MetricTelemetry();
        metric.MetricNamespace = "xxxxx";
        client.TrackMetric(metric);
```